# :host styling not getting applied in angular6

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to change the `outline` color for `mat-form-field`.

```
 :host /deep/ .mat-form-field-appearance-outline :host /deep/ .mat-form-field-outline {
    color: white;
}
```

This is however not working. Using `:host` seems to be the issue because the following works fine:

```
/deep/ .mat-form-field-appearance-outline /deep/ .mat-form-field-outline {
    color: white;
}
```

But if I do not use `:host`, this style is getting applied to other components as well. I am not sure why `:host` is not working.

Comment: I have seen some strange behavior with CSS with the material design too.  Part of my problem was that behind the scenes, the material design directives are adding inline styles (via attribute) to the html tags so that obviously is the last thing in the cascade.  I'm not sure if that's your problem, but the only way I could solve it was to not use the material design directive, but instead just use the html element it renders and then apply the styles by hand to "mock" the mat design.  That might be rough with a form field though.

Comment: where do you write that style? in global `styles.css` or in `component.css`? it would be easier to spot your problem if you share your template code and style file.

Comment: @ysf I am writing it in component.scss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem with following code is the second `:host` selector. because it cannot match any host element after matching `.mat-form-field-appearance-outline`

```
:host /deep/ .mat-form-field-appearance-outline :host /deep/ .mat-form-field-outline {
    color: white;
}
```

when second `:host` selector is removed it works in a way that it applies styles to current component and all of its children. (btw second `/deep/` selector is also unnecessary)

following code differs from previous one in a way that, absence of `:host` selector makes this style truly global. so it applies all components in component tree. ie. all ancestors and children.

```
/deep/ .mat-form-field-appearance-outline /deep/ .mat-form-field-outline {
    color: white;
}
```

above concepts are explained [in here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

> Applying the ::ng-deep pseudo-class to any CSS rule completely
>   disables view-encapsulation for that rule. Any style with ::ng-deep
>   applied becomes a global style. In order to scope the specified style
>   to the current component and all its descendants, be sure to include
>   the :host selector before ::ng-deep. If the ::ng-deep combinator is
>   used without the :host pseudo-class selector, the style can bleed into
>   other components.

so when you use `:host /deep/` on any css selector it selects elements within current component and its children. in order prevent it affecting any children you should make your selector more specific by adding a custom class to elements you want to select and combine it with `:host /deep/` selector such that;

```
:host /deep/ .redOutline.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
    color: white;
}
```

and add `redOutline` class to `mat-form-field` elements you want to select.

here is a working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qy7g4r